# Create new column that connects 2 existing columns in a data frame

Tags: r

Hi I want to create a 3rd column in a data frame that combines 2 existing columns in the same data frame.

For example I have columns A and B and they have nulls on some rows. I want to create a new column C where it combines the values in A and B so that it will get rid of the nulls.

```
> A <- c('Tall', '', '', 'small')
> B <- c('','mid','medium','' )
> AB <-data.frame(A,B)
> AB
      A      B
1  Tall       
2          mid
3       medium
4 small
```

I need to create Column C where it fills the rows whichever has the value on either A or B

```
> AB
      A      B      C
1  Tall          Tall
2          mid    mid
3       medium medium
4 small         small
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply` and remove all NA.

```
AB$C <- apply(AB, 1, function(x) {
  paste(setdiff(x, NA), collapse = "")
})
AB
      A      B      C
1  Tall          Tall
2          mid    mid
3       medium medium
4 small         small
```

Or use `tidyr::unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
AB %>%
  unite(C, c(A, B), sep = "", remove = FALSE)
       C     A      B
1   Tall  Tall       
2    mid          mid
3 medium       medium
4  small small
```

Use `remove = TRUE`, if you don't want the original columns A and B